# How to send data from to local server

Tags: python, request, http.client

I am working on wireless hand gesture bot project. I want to send output of hand gesture to bot. 
I created a server on raspberry pi using flask and trying to send data through request module but its showing '405 Method Not Allowed

## Method Not Allowed

The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

'

On client side

```
import requests
r = requests.post("http://192.168.43.133/", data={'foo': 'bar'})
# And done.
print(r.text) # displays the result body.
```

on server side

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
        return "Hello"

if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=80,debug= True)
```

Comment: straight from the flask docs, `By default, a route only answers to GET requests` so you'll have to modify your flask app to accept `POST` requests, which you can find --> http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#http-methods

Answer (score 0):

Ref: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.route

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
        return "Hello"
```

The `app.route("/")` only maps the `GET` http verb by default. You're trying to do a POST. So it won't work. 
Try this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
        return "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks. i have a variable 'fingers' whose value changes . Can u tell how to send value of finger to server.